# NRefactory parsed code - is class currently inheriting?

Tags: nrefactory

What is the best way to identify, on a NFactory parsed tree, if the current class is actually inheriting (or not) from another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should see if the parsed tree has any basetypes or not.

```
TypeDeclaration typeDeclaration = new CSharpParser().Parse("public class A:B{}").Children.OfType<TypeDeclaration>().First();
        if(typeDeclaration.ClassType==ClassType.Class && typeDeclaration.BaseTypes.Count>=1)
        {
                //this class is inherited..
        }
```